# How do you animate the pagination of command-f results?

Tags: javascript, web, animation

For example, search (command-f) "const" on [30secondsofcode.org](https://30secondsofcode.org/) and paginate through each result with the enter button. It animates whereas on a regular webpage, the webpage would just jump to the next result with no animation.

Comment: Got my first downvote within 2 minutes and with only four views. That's a new record for me! Apparently, someone thinks this question should be closed for being "too broad". Well, I listed a very specific example. Not sure how I can make this question any more specific...

Comment: In general, it is a very good idea to show what you have tried for a particular problem. The brevity of this question may be interpreted by readers as meaning you did no research at all, even if that is not true. It's also generally not worth adding "I searched for hours and hours and found nothing at all", since readers tend not to believe that `:-)`. If you can find something, try something and show sometime, even if it does not work, that will get you upvotes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
scroll-behavior: smooth
```

You can actually find it on the page you linked if you look at the styles of the 'html' tag.

Also note that this isn't supported on all browsers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior